# How to extract name of all files contained in a folder into a .txt file?

Tags: linux, terminal, extract

I want to extract name of all files contained in a folder into a .txt file for ex: when we type ls command in terminal it shows list all the files and folder names.
Can we store all these names in a .txt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect the output of the `ls` command to a file with `>` like so:

`ls > files.txt`

Note this will overwrite any previous contents of `files.txt`. To append, use `>>` instead like so:

`ls >> files.txt`

Answer (score 1):

By using the `>` character, a command's output can be written to a named file. For example,

```
ls > list.txt
```

This will directly post the output of the `ls` command into the file `list.txt`. However, this will also *overwrite* anything that's in `list.txt`. To append to the end of a file instead of overwriting, use `>>`:

```
ls >> list.txt
```

This will leave the previous contents of `list.txt` in tact, and add the output of `ls` to the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you really care about *files* and want to skip directories, I'd use find.

```
find . -type f --mindepth 1 --maxdepth 1 >> list.txt
```

Note, that this list will also contain `list.txt`, as it is created before spawning `find` in the current directory.

The advantage of using `find` instead of `ls` is that it will include "hidden" files (files starting with a `.` in their name).